# Camera pose estimation is inverted

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a Structure from Motion framework for generating 3D models of moving objects with fixed cameras. To do this, I am following this pipeline:

1. Obtain the fundamental matrix F through keypoints. As I am still in development and I can not (yet) access the final objects I will model, I am doing this with a small object and manually annotated keypoint pairs between two images: 
   [These](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAzSy.jpg) are the correspondences used to calculate F. Computing the error of F by `x'Fx` where x' are the points from the right image and x the points of the left image (in pixel coordinates) gives an error of 0,1196.
2. Compute the essential matrix E using the intrinsic matrices and the fundamental: `E = Kleft'*F*Kright` where Kleft' is the inverse intrinsic matrix of the left camera. With the SVD decomposition I create a new E, which has only two singular values equal to 1.
3. Decompose E to get R and t. To do so, I have used a self made custom version of OpenCV [recoverPose()](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gadb7d2dfcc184c1d2f496d8639f4371c0) function, that allows for two different camera matrices.
4. Obtain Pleft as a diagonal matrix and Pright as the construction of R and t.

Here are the significant parts of the code:

```
F = findFundamentalMat( alignedLeft.points, alignedRight.points, mask, RANSAC);
E = cameraMatrixLeftInv*F*cameraMatrixRight;
SVD::compute(E, w, u, vt);

Mat diag = Mat::zeros(Size(3,3),6);
diag.at<double>(0,0) = 1;
diag.at<double>(1,1) = 1;       
E = u*diag*vt;
int good = recoverPoseFromTwoCameras(E,alignedLeft.points,alignedRight.points,intrinsicsLeft.K,intrinsicsRight.K,R,t,mask);
Pleft = Matx34f::eye();
Pright = Matx34f(R.at<double>(0,0), R.at<double>(0,1), R.at<double>(0,2), t.at<double>(0),
                 R.at<double>(1,0), R.at<double>(1,1), R.at<double>(1,2), t.at<double>(1),
                 R.at<double>(2,0), R.at<double>(2,1), R.at<double>(2,2), t.at<double>(2));
```

Then I use viz to visualize the camera poses:

```
viz::Viz3d myWindow("Results");
viz::WCameraPosition cameraLeft(imgLeft->getIntrinsics().K,imgLeft->getImage());
viz::WCameraPosition cameraRight(imgRight->getIntrinsics().K,imgRight->getImage());
```

Which I place in the viewer using Pleft and Pright:

```
myWindow.showWidget("cameraLeft",cameraLeft,Affine3d(Pleft(Range::all(),Range(0,3)),Pleft.col(3)));
myWindow.showWidget("cameraRight",cameraRight,Affine3d(Pright(Range::all(),Range(0,3)),Pright.col(3)));
```

However, if I do that, the result is inverted. I can't embed more than one link because of low reputation, but the camera1 is where the camera 2 should be and viceversa.

But if I apply the matrices like this:

```
myWindow.showWidget("cameraLeft",cameraLeft,Affine3d(Pright(Range::all(),Range(0,3)),Pleft.col(3)));
myWindow.showWidget("cameraRight",cameraRight,Affine3d(Pleft(Range::all(),Range(0,3)),Pleft.col(3)));
```

The result is correct.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have worked out! If you have not, you'd better upload more data. For example, the features, the F/E you computed, the camera intrinsic. Then we can test your code and try to find your bug, otherwise, there are many possible for this.

Comment: I haven't yet, but I have moved on to reconstructing the points, as a preliminary result gave a good structure. As the final project will rely on optical flow (and not feature matching) to get the fundamental Matrix, I am advancing on the reconstruction/mesh generation/texture mapping. 

I will keep this post updated if I find the solution, but I do believe it was due to a missunderstanding of the openCV function/algebra involved.